# Как добиться такого же поведения при другой реализации?

Tags: javascript, функции, замыкания

```js
var makeBuffer = (function () {
    var box = [];

    function buffer (item) {
        if (item) {
            box.push(item)
        } else {
            return box
        }
    }

    buffer.clean = function () {
        box = [];
    }

    return buffer;
})();


makeBuffer(10);
makeBuffer(15);
console.log(makeBuffer());
makeBuffer.clean();
console.log(makeBuffer());
```

Как добиться такого поведения при использовании "FunctionDeclaration" ?
Что бы функцию можно использовать и до ее обьявления

```
function имя(параметры) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рецепт прост: берёте костыль подходящего размера, приматываете изолентой, и можно начинать крутить педали.

```js
makeBuffer(10);
makeBuffer(15);
console.log(makeBuffer());
makeBuffer.clean();
console.log(makeBuffer());


function makeBuffer(item) {
    if(!makeBuffer.box) {
      makeBuffer.box = [];
      makeBuffer.clean = function () {
          this.box = [];
      }
    }
    
    if (item) {
        makeBuffer.box.push(item)
    } else {
        return makeBuffer.box
    }
}
```